# Center row of Buttons in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am adding buttons in a UIScrollView dynamically, but some views only have two buttons and some have 10. I want to center the buttons in the scroll view so It doesn't look like I built them from the left to right. I've tried several tricks from SO and nothing seems to work. setting the content offset was my first approach, but doesn't have the effect I want.

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void)addButton:(UIButton *)button {
CGFloat contentWidth = 0.0f;
CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;   
if ([_scrollView.subviews count] == 0) {

    buttonFrame.origin.x = self.contentIndicatorWidth + kButtonSeperator;
    contentWidth = self.contentIndicatorWidth + buttonFrame.size.width + self.contentIndicatorWidth;
} else {
    contentWidth = _scrollView.contentSize.width;
    UIButton *lastButton = [_scrollView.subviews lastObject];
    buttonFrame.origin.x = lastButton.frame.origin.x + lastButton.frame.size.width + kButtonSeperator;
    contentWidth += buttonFrame.size.width + kButtonSeperator;
}
button.frame = buttonFrame;
[_scrollView addSubview:button];
 _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth *kContentMultiplicityFactor, _scrollView.frame.size.height);
 [_buttons setValue:button forKey:button.titleLabel.text];
totalWidth = contentWidth;
```

// [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:[self getButtonAtIndex:0].frame animated:YES];
}

Comment: Are you adding UIButtons directly into UIScrollView or adding it into a UIView and then adding it to UIScrollView?

Comment: I'm adding the buttons to the scroll view directly as in the code above.

Comment: To form each row of buttons, you will send separate NSArray of buttons, like first row 3 buttons, second row 10 buttons and third row 6 buttons. Am i correct?

Comment: I'm already creating the row of buttons. I just want to center them. They appear left to right at position 0.

Comment: You can add those buttons in a UIView and then, make the UIView center of the UIScrollView. Will the approach work for you?

Comment: No effect doing that. I really want to calculate the center by using the total width of each button and centering that content in the visible area.

Comment: Ok, if you add buttons inside UIView, you need not have to position every button, you then have to center only UIView based on total width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add the buttons call this method:

```
- (void)centerButtons:(NSArray*)buttons {
  CGSize scrollViewSize = _scrollView.bounds.size;

  // Measure the total width taken by the buttons
  CGFloat width = 0;
  for (UIButton* b in buttons)
    width += b.bounds.size.width + kButtonSeparator;
  if (width > kButtonSeparator)
    width -= kButtonSeparator;

  // If the buttons width is shorter than the visible bounds, adjust origin
  CGFloat origin = 0;
  if (width < scrollViewSize.width)
    origin = (scrollViewSize.width - width) / 2.f;

  // Place buttons
  CGFloat x = origin;
  CGFloat y = 0;
  for (UIButton* b in buttons) {
    b.center = CGPointMake(x + b.bounds.size.width/2.f, y + b.bounds.size.height/2.f);
    x += b.bounds.size.width + kButtonSeparator;
  }

  _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(scrollViewSize.width, width), scrollViewSize.height);
}
```

Comment: you're a genius... This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @aleph7 Could you please give the same solution for buttons arranged in an UIView,I am not using any scroll view,adding them directly on the view

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya just replace _scrollView with your view and remove the last line setting the content size.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this isn't a very hard problem. I guess you add these buttons on the fly.

You have a scrollview called ScrollView and you have already put in content size.

So you have 10 buttons of different widths :

```
int btnCount = 10;
int totalWidth = 0;
int spacing = 5;
NSMUtableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<btnCount-1; i++) {
    UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [b setTitle:@"some title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b sizeToFit];
    CGRect frame = b.frame;
    totalWidth += b.frame.size.width;
    [buttons addObject:b];
}
totalWidth += (btnCount * spacing);
UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, totalWidth, 40)];
int priorButtonX = 0;
for (UIButton *b in buttons) {
    CGRect frame = b.frame;
    frame.origin.x = priorButtonX;
    b.frame = frame;
    priorButtonX = frame.origin.x + spacing;
    [btnView addSubview:b];
}

int scrollSizeWidth = scrollView.contentSize.width;
int placeX = (scrollSizeWidth /2) - (btnView.frame.size.width /2)

CGRect btnViewFrame = btnView.frame;
btnViewFrame.origin.x = placeX;
bbtnView.frame = btnViewFrame;

[scrollView addSubView:btnView];
```

You might want to do something with Y placement, but that one is very simple. This code can be written in fewer lines, and use fewer variables, but this is done to make it easier to read.

Comment: This works perfect to center the content in the scroll view. I apologize for not articulating what I wanted very well, but I want the buttons to be centered in the visible area if there are fewer buttons than the visible width of the area they are displayed in. In this example, the buttons center in the scroll view, but that puts half of the buttons off to the right off screen since the scrollviews size is larger than the view it is contained in.

Comment: I reposted the code I am using. I add each button on the fly in this manner. I just want them to center if the total buttons are less than the visible width...

Comment: When you calculate the total width, it isup to you if you use content size or if you check the frame of the scroll view. A simple if statement would do the trick